# How to save modifications to apply later?

Tags: php, database

The moderators of my webapp have the possibility to **modify some data** in the database. Those modifications are visible by all the users. But for some reason, I don't want them to apply immediately, but rather **only after a specific action**, for instance, when I explicitly accept. The timeline is:

1. A field in a table has the value `PreviousValue`.
2. A moderator requests this value to be `NewValue`.
   All users continue to see the value `PreviousValue`.
3. I accept the change.
   All users now see the value `NewValue`.

The problem is that the moderators can modify fields in a **high number of tables**. What is the best way to handle this temporary values? I can imagine these solutions, but none of them sounds good:

- Duplicate all the tables (having together `MyTable` and `MyTable_ToApply`).
- Add a special table (`ToApplyTable`) with four fields : the table to modify, the field to modify, the ID of the entry to modify and the new value to apply.

Do you have better ideas?

Comment: The second solution sounds much much better, but what about the cases where you primary key (id) consists of more than one field? The first solution is pretty straightforward and if keep in mind that you will have only one entry at each table_ToApply it won't affect you very much.

Comment: @alkis Actually, both solutions are really dirty, as you highlight one of the problem. Hence my question here. For the first solution, it implies to duplicate all the tables, and I'm using an ORM, so I also must duplicate all the entites. That's not really acceptable.

Comment: Why can't you have a field that holds the value the current value and one that holds the new value, and every time you want to accept it, the new value replaces the old, and the field that holds the new value goes null?

Comment: @alkis Too many (most of the time useless) fields!

Comment: Upvoted. I really want to see a good answer in this one. Please, when you decide what you'll do post your decision.

Comment: How big are the tables? Unless we are talking huge amounts of data, having duplicate fields in the same table seems to be the most common sense solution. If space is the problem, your second solutions is OK. If you don't care about keeping the changelog you could even delete entries after they are applied to production from such table and save space.

Comment: @cen The problem is not the space, it's about duplicating all the fields in the entities.

Comment: What database are we talking about? Please add the tag for it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos We're talking about a MySQL database, but the question is general.

Comment: Can you add to your question what kind of data we're talking (articles, posts, quotes) and describe the webapp. I'd like to provide an answer that fits your app, instead of a DB. (design the DB around the app, not the other way around)

Comment: @puredevotion Moderators are almost all-mighty in my webapp, which is a web-based game. They can change the cost of a military unit, the description of a building, …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as question quite broad (and can have many good answers) - this is not an answer, but another possible solution:

you can have table like:

```
id - just autogenerated number
datetime - date of change
changed_by - string with name of actor or id of some user
oldvalue - just old value
newvalue - just new value
update_insert_sql - here you put actual SQL which should be executed (you already have this sql in your current code)
state - 0 - it is not applied to db, 1 - already executed, 2 - you're rejected this change
datetime_of_apply - just date of action
datetime_of_reject - just date of action
```

NOTE: instead of storing old value, you can store SQL to fetch current value, this will help you when there are several changes from different moderators to the same row/column

so, in your interface you will be able to see all proposed changes to all tables, see only actual value and proposed new value and update db if needed

possible addition: to populate this table you can use triggers, instead of changing current code

Comment: A generic solution, which does not imply to modify the current tables. Well, it does not really respect all the relational databases principles, but OK… Can you think of a way to use the same principle with an ORM ?

Comment: can you elaborate why one should store SQL code in a cell? Storing application logic in a table seems of to me, and I don't really see how this helps when there a multiple changes from moderators...

Comment: Yeah! It was indeed, the shortest one. Nice one dude. +1

Comment: @puredevotion Yep, I won't store the SQL, but rather the name of the table to modify. Well, actually, that's pretty much the second solution I proposed. All the other answers are really good, but don't suit my project (with Doctrine 2, and already well advanced) very well. For multiple changes, I've just to add an other entry to the table.

Comment: i agree with puredevotion. and also, @blackhole, if you use doctrine it is because you want database abstraction, that is a very good pattern, and if you save table names in other tables, you are doing the opposite, and also getting a weakness. also, you have will to put code in the controller to decide what field to use, and thats not clean, and  is crazy for sorting a searching. I dont care about the bounty but please, do the things well. wordpress joomla and others blog/CMS uses the same table for posts and revisions. sometimes you dont have to decide about things other people already did

Comment: @Blackhole, also with revisions as new rows int the same table, related to main and unpublished, if you use doctrine, you just need a repository, and field to consider, somethinf like: $rep->findByPublished(1) all the rest of the code remains the same, so your controllers are not aware of business-level logic like which are moderated or not, and don't have to the deal with it. then in your administrator controller you write the logic to set a revision as the main post and unpublish the old when the revision is accepted. easy, clean, scalable, maintainable, and a valid model.

Comment: @Blackhole you can store serialized ORM object into table as blob field

Comment: @puredevotion storing of select SQL can help you to see current value (not current at the moment of edit)

Answer (score 3):

This is how wordpress deal with this stuff. You can have in the same table, a published post, and then, as new rows, a collection of unpublished revisions, by different authors, created in diferent moments, and of course associated to the main post.

**Update**

For instance if you use doctrine,  you just need the same repository, and a field to consider, something like: `$rep->findByPublished(1)` all the rest of the code remains the same, so your controllers are not aware of business-level logic like which are moderated or not, and don't have to the deal with it. then in your administrator controller you write the logic to set a revision as the main post and unpublish the old when the revision is accepted. easy, clean, scalable, maintainable, and a valid model.

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

   `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', #date of creation of this post o revision




  `post_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish', #publish, unpublish, 

  `post_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', #internal name if you want to better identify revisions

  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', #date of modification of this current post or revision

  `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', #if this is a revision, here you have the id of the main post this could replace if it it approved

  `post_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post', //basicaly in your case, post or revision, but you can remove this one, since you can check if post_parent is 0 (or NULL if you want)


  ##Other columns with all the post information 



  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),

)
```

I dont like how wordpress is made, but i have to say that this is a great approach. And, four sure:

- dont even think about having extra columns, since you will be able to save too few meta data, and also will have to modify the database if you decide that some other columns are elegible to be edited.
- dont have more than one revision in the same field. This is against all the relational databases principles. You could have serialized info for some metadata and that could be ok in some case, but for this that is main information, it will be imposible to handle and parse in many situations.
- You could have a helper table, the model will be valid, but it will be harder do to searches, sorts, and actually you will have two tables exactly the same, so it isnt the best idea.

Comment: do they seriously have a varchar(20) for the boolean var publish/unpublish?

Comment: Nope, there are a bunch of posibilities. I just used this to explain in what it can be related to the actual cuestion. For sure some colums would need to be adapted, not only in what concerns to sata types, to get an optimized table that fits the current model. Anyways...wordpress has too many things that makes no sense, I could tell you a lot. But what I tried to ilustrate here is just how to deal with this of the diferent revisions, and the approach is good, though the didnt do the best with types

Answer (score 3):

When an update happens, create a new row and have a flag that a moderator needs to look at it.  When moderators accepts, flag the accepted record as active, and the previous record as inactive. Do this at the highest level so that if you have other tables joining off of this they inherit the active / inactive state and the is_moderated flag.

```
id | text      | is_active | is_moderated | is_accepted
-------------------------------------------------------
1  | hello     | 1         | 1            | 1             <-- This is the active row
```

New record is added changing hello to goodbye

```
id | text      | is_active | is_moderated | is_accepted
-------------------------------------------------------
1  | hello     | 1         | 1            | 1             <-- This is still the active row
2  | goodbye   | 0         | 0            | 0             <-- Moderator needs to accept or deny this
```

Accepted Result:

```
id | text      | is_active | is_moderated | is_accepted
-------------------------------------------------------
1  | hello     | 0         | 1            | 1             <-- This is NOT the active row
2  | goodbye   | 1         | 1            | 1             <-- Accepted, new active row
```

Denied State:

```
id | text      | is_active | is_moderated | is_accepted
-------------------------------------------------------
1  | hello     | 1         | 1            | 1             <-- This is still the active row
2  | goodbye   | 0         | 1            | 0             <-- Moderator denied
```

Your selected query becomes:

To get active row:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE is_active = 1
```

To get rows requiring moderation

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE is_moderated = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the answer is not so difficult. Here's is my idea:-
**Step 1 :**
Just add a column to your table `Posts`(or the table containing the entire posts by the users) named `Moderated Post`. Any moderation or edits by any moderator goes into this column.

**Step 2 :**
Add another column to the table `Posts` named `isModerated`. This contains a value `1` or `0` just like the boolean `true` or `false`. 

**Step 3 :**Now, you are almost done. You have got a table like this :-

```
                      TABLE `POSTS`

| Post id | Initial Post | Moderated Post | isModerated |
_________________________________________________________
          | The first    |                |             |
|    1    | post goes    |                |      0      |
|         | here         |                |             |
_________________________________________________________
|         | The second   | The moderated  |             |
|    2    | post goes    | post goes here |      0      |
|         | here         |(Post invisible)|             |
_________________________________________________________
|         | The third    | The moderated  |             |
|    3    | post goes    | post goes here |      1      |
|         | here         | (Post visible) |             |
_________________________________________________________
```

Now in your php code, after retrieving all the values from the table, you display your post like this ( JUST A ROUGH SKETCH) :-

```
<?php 
if($isModerated == 1) { 
   echo $moderated_post; 
}else {
   echo $initial_post;
}
?>
```

## **For changes in numerous tables**

As you said that the moderation changes values in a number of tables, for that you have to add the column **(`Moderated_Value1`) x n** where n denotes number of columns whose values can be changed. Example :-

```
| Value 1 | Value 2 | Moderated_Value1 | Moderated_Value2 |
|   0     |    1    |      1000        |     2000         |
```

Now, your code becomes :-

```
<?php 
if($isModerated == 1) { 
   echo $moderated_post; 
   echo $moderated_value1;
   echo $moderated_value2;
}else {
   echo $initial_post;
   echo value1;
   echo value2;
}
?>
```

Using this method, there is also an advantage that you can easily rollback the moderation by changing isModerated value in the table from 1 to 0

Comment: This implies to duplicate all the fields that the moderators can change in all tables. It's a too heavy solution.

Comment: NOT DUPLICATE @Blackhole ! If the post has not been moderated, the `Moderated_Value` in all the tables INCLUDING THE MAIN POSTS TABLE will be null. The value of the `Moderated_Value` columns will only be other than null only if there has been some moderation in dat post. When the post has been moderated, you get the moderated value in the column with `isModerated` be 0 i.e., `status pending`. It is only after you allow access to that moderation that the value of `isModerated` will become 1 i.e., `LIVE`. You just have to insert n number of columns in your tables and later modify them with code.

Comment: By "duplicate", I mean "having two field", and not "having the contents twice".

Comment: Ohk @Blackhole , then I frame my answer as "YEAH! OBVIOUSLY! If you want your moderation to be strong, then you must have something "HEAVY" in your code. You can't expect it to be a few lines of extra code and get SO-kind of moderation."

Comment: Blackhole is right, this is the less scalable and less maintainable solution ever. You will have double wide tables, and thats not a good solution, and moreover, with many columns being null. Or otherwise you will have to alter the table whenever you change your mind about what can be moderated. A table has to match a valid entity-relation model, and this table just does not . And you can only have one draft per post, so, besides, it has limitations. This is a pretty bad idea and should be avoided. I bet money you couldnt find any serious system using this kind of week model.

Comment: Thats why I downvote, since I believe this is against dessign patterns and principles widely stablished and we cannot spread it as a good prractice.

Comment: @CarlosRobles, there is no problem in this kind of arrangement as when the SQL query is made, you just have to make a query of just 1 extra column, i.e., the `isModerated` column in the main `POSTS` table. If it is 0, then there is no need to EVEN BROWSE the `Moderated_Value` columns which may HARDLY AFFECT the entire processing time. So, according to me, this must be the MOST CONVENIENT way of handling moderation. While in your answer, you have to make a SEPARATE TABLE, this is a very BAD WAY as it may increase the processing time by leaps and bounds.

Comment: In my answer, as you can read, I use the same table. So please read and try to understand. Also, your code needs a bunch of if else in the controller side, and that is crazy.

Answer (score 2):

An Idea: add a revision number to all tables. When someone makes a change, the unique revision number of this change is stored in all affected rows. Instead of updates, a row with a higher revision number and same id is inserted. Id column must not set to be unique of course. Currently active revision number is stored in a table that just holds this number. Then you generate DB views that look like the former tables but if 2 rows have the same id, it only gets the entry with the highest revision number that is equal or lower to the active revision. In your app you use the views instead of the original tables.
You can then review the changes in the original tables, delete the ones you don't accept, and raise the currently active revision to accept all changes you have not deleted.

Comment: Really nice solution, but hard to do with an ORM like Doctrine, sadly…

Answer (score 2):

You could add revision to your tables and have a composite primary key

lets suppose you have this table

```
id -> Integer PK
comment -> text
user -> integer
```

if you add this fields

```
revision -> integer PK with id
published -> boolean -- this will tell you wich one is active
```

You can add some more audit fields, like some dates to check when the new revision is created or who creted the revision

and the login to get wich version is easy, you can select any revision by its revision number, or you can get the active one...

of course, this will give you some troubles with concurency (2 people modifying the very same row at the same time... but you can use semaphores, or something like that), you cannot keep using generators / autoincremets for your inserts, (ok, you could use generators ONLY for new records).

another way is, if you dont want to store all the change history, and only need the last edition, is to add a text field, and save a serialized array with the edited values, and whe you approve, just run the update on fields.

there are plenty of ways, you can use this aproch of serialization and use an aux table to hold the history, and mix both aproche, put in the aux table the origin id, the revision, and the serialized array, and you have both... the serialized version with all the revisions....

pick the one wich best describe your situation....

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is to store all changed data in an array (array[$table][$field][$id]=$value), then store it in a simple table with a TEXT type field, in json encoding. This way you'll have also enough flexibility to change (add) othrer controls without changing the edit table structure. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can easily work backwards and figure out the **WORST** choices to see what the least bad choice is, if you don't think there's any **GOOD** choice. Each choice requires sacrifices. But what are the sacrifices in question?

**Option #1**: Duplicate all the tables (having together MyTable and MyTable_ToApply).

IMO this would be a giant headache. Talk about too many fields! You would also need to create extra coding just to move data from one table to another. I think there's just too much that could go wrong here.

**Option #2**: Add a special table (`ToApplyTable`) with four fields : the table to modify, the field to modify, the ID of the entry to modify and the new value to apply.

I think this is also a dirty option as you mentioned, because of the same thing - moving values from one table to another.

**Option #3**: Add `date` and `ismoderated` values to a table.

This has been mentioned by a lot of people. Your argument is that it is too many (mostly useless) columns. I think it is better than anything else that has been mentioned. I will humbly propose one final method which is a bit of a combination of option #1 and option #3.

**Option #4**: Create a custom `ismoderated` table under each table that can have moderated fields.

I do something like this in my database and use the naming standard `[TABLENAME]__ismoderated`. In this table you don't really need more than one column, if you only want one. You can simply have the foreign key in this table of items that need moderating, and then delete the key when it has finally been moderated. Alternatively, you could add the moderator's user ID here and the time added as additional fields if you wanted to.

I personally think I would go with the datetime field as well so you have the ability to follow changes and know which one is the most recent.

In any case, this gives you the ability to `INNER JOIN` both tables. If you only want to see values to be moderated.

Answer (score 1):

Many answers have been given, and I feel that most are very reasonable. I believe there are a few good ways of doing this.

I'm making the assumptions that processing power/speed is more important/costly than storage space in both HDD and RAM.
I also agree with Mr. Robbes (somewhere above me) that there should be one revision per row/cell, and adding extra columns isn't a correct solution (see below for an elaboration)

**Let me first start with options that I *don't* think are correct:**

- JSON/noSQL. your data is clearly relational. (my)SQL is the way to
  go.
- Store as an array or other form of application memory. The
  overhead this creates, including the burden on every player is not
  worth it. Plus you want to be able to store this, and go over these
  revisions in time, and keeping it as part of the application stacks
  up over time. It is simply not worth it.
- Add one or more columns added to every table.
  The changes created can be stored there. As you mentioned, this creates a
  sizable overhead in the table(s) and is a bad practise. However, this is a proper solution when for example only posts or any other single entity needs to be edited and no history needs to be saved. However, this is all not the case in this question.

Looking at the facts given in the question:

1. there are one or more tables with items that can be moderated,
2. there are multiple moderators that can create multiple revisions
3. these revisions are not always chronologically applied
4. you might want to keep record of all suggested and applied records

I think the *second solution you provided* is the best fit with your data.

- Create a separate table for revisions. This is the best normalized way of doing this. Depending on the scale of moderation, you can either keep a copy of the full row that's being edited, or make a reference to the specific cells that are being edited.
- For extra expert level-points you can use something like views or temporary tables to create a table that has all the definite rows, and not show any pending or declined revisions. This could improve speed, but does rely on serious database engineering. Not something you want to mess up

Pushing revisions to your users can be done by a variety of ways. Using the above temporary table/view, you use a stored procedure to change what's in the table (or set a cell to "active"and update the temp-table/view)
You can simply replace a row in the database with the new one (updates are expensive though), or use a join construction.

If CPU is cheaper than storage, then looking at a git-like system with hashes or so might work.

Answer (score 0):

However the moderators will change the data using forms..

When they change the data, why shall you not save the data in the csv files...

While you revise the changes, you can insert into the actual table..

Its an idea only..